# What does TIMER.start() do if the timer is already started in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript

The document doesn't mention anything about this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#start%28%29

Anyone knows for **sure**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just nothing :) I've tested it

> Starts the timer, *if it is not already
>   running*.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is right on the page you linked:

> Starts the timer, if it is not already running.